# how to increase the size above 5 mb while uploading the pdf file

Tags: codeigniter, pdf

**while uploading the pdf file i want to increase the size above 5 mb,below code only allowing the 2 mb how to increase the size above 5 mb please help me any one and resolve the my problem**

```
public function question_upload() {           
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('examname', 'Select Exam Type', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('assignment', 'Subject Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('question', 'Content Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('subcontent', 'Sub Content Name', 'required');
    if (empty($_FILES['picture']['name'])) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('picture', 'Pdf', 'required');
    }
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    $data['h'] = $this->Faculty_Model->faculty_QuestionDisplay();
    $data['studentAnswer'] = $this->Faculty_Model->student_Question();
    $this->load->view('index1', $data);
    } else {
    if (!empty($_FILES['picture']['name']))         
    $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/files/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif|pdf';
    $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['picture']['name'];   
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if ($this->upload->do_upload('picture')) {
    $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
    $picture = $uploadData['file_name'];
    } else {
    $picture = '';
    }
    } else {
    $picture = '';
    }
    $userData = array(
    'datee' => $this->input->post('datee'),
    'examname' => $this->input->post('examname'),
    'assignment_name' => $this->input->post('assignment'),
    'question   ' => $this->input->post('question'),
    'subcontent' => $this->input->post('subcontent'),
    'pdffile' => $picture
    );
    $this->Faculty_Model->faculty_Questioninsert($userData);

    $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'User data have been added successfully.');
    redirect('welcome/index1');
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the value of upload_max_filesize in your php.ini :

upload_max_filesize =2M defalt
upload_max_filesize = 5M

```
          (or)
```

you need to add the below line in code config.php (root path public_html/application/config)

ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '5M');

```
          (or)
```

You need to add the below line of code .htaccess
php_value upload_max_filesize 5M

Answer (score 0):

```
place the constructor inside or class inside it will work

class Home_model extends CI_Model {

/**
 * @return void
 * */
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper("security");       
    ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '5M');
}
```